# Javascript onload after ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After returning to main content by ajax load, function `onload` didn't run.
I can understand why, but how can I make it run in that condition?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        onload = function() {
            if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
            var rows = document.getElementById('chat').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rows[i].onclick = function() {
                    $("#chat_main").load("chat", {
                       m: this.id,
                       ajax: 1 //here we are loading another page
                   });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function return_to_main() {
            $("#chat_main").load("chat", {
                ajax: 1 //here we trying to load back main page
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**P.S.** `return_to_main()` is binded on `input type="button"`

Comment: `onload` not appear to be called ?

Comment: `onload = function` is BAD practice. If you want your code to find the new content, you need to rerun the code.

Comment: @guest271314 that is same thing as `window.onload = function(){}`

Comment: @epascarello can you elaborate on _"`onload = function` is BAD practice"_? Tools like JSLint sometimes even require it to get rid of warnings about define-before-use.

Comment: @epascarello Not being redfined , overwritten by `onload = fn` ? Did not get to changing name of function, to, perhaps `_onload` ?

Comment: @Halcyon The code is `window.onload = function(){}`. Dropping `window` is bad practice and it should be ideally be using `addEventListener`

Comment: @epascarello Certain OP was attempting to call `window.onload` ? , or define, call a function named "onload" after completeion of `.load()` ? , where calling `.load()` should not replace entire `document` , or `window`

Comment: @epascarello ah, so your beef is with the missing declaration `var onload`?

Comment: @Halcyon http://jsfiddle.net/jcchjh00/

Comment: @epascarello yea, so: http://jsfiddle.net/jcchjh00/1/

Comment: @Aero Is expected result to overwrite `window.onload` ?, or call a function named "onload" following calling `.load()` ? Unclear, here, what exact requirement is ? fwiw, call to jQuery `.load()` should not replace current `window` with new `window` , but instead insert `html` , returned data , into `$("#chat_main")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function after the request:

```
$("#chat_main").load("chat", {
    ajax: 1 //here we trying to load back main page
}).done(onload); // <--
```

If `.load` does not produce a promise use:

```
$("#chat_main").load("chat", {
    ajax: 1 //here we trying to load back main page
}, onload); // <--
```

Comment: I don't think `.load` returns a deferred / jqXHR, so `.done` won't work here.

Comment: If it doesn't return a promise you can use the 3rd parameter as a complete callback: `.load("foo", {}, onload);`

Comment: @Halcyon jQuery throws me a ``TypeError: $(...).load(...).done is not a function``

Comment: Then pass the callback as a 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to the window.onload call. It does not magically get called every time the page content is updated. It is only called once. You need to call a function every time you want the code to run. So when the Ajax call is complete, you would been to trigger it.

BUT You are using jQuery so use it.

There is no reason why you would need to bind to every row on the table. Use event delegation. Now when the content changes, you will still have the events bound.

```
$( function () {  //document ready
    var chatMain = $("#chat_main");
    chatMain.on("click", "table tbody tr", function () {  //listen for clicks on table row
        chatMain.load("chat",
            {
                m: this.id,
                ajax: 1 //here we are loading another page
            }
        );
    });
});
```